# Tensorflow.js using custom layers with already trained models

Tags: keras, tensorflow.js

I've converted a trained keras model into tensorflow.js, and I am now trying to implement it in react-native. The model converts fine, but when I try to load it in, it says

Error: Unknown activation: swish

I know it is possible to make custom layers, but I'm not sure if this is applicable to a model that has already been trained.

Any work arounds?

Code: 
Swift.js

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

class Swish extends tf.layers.Layer {
    constructor(config) {
      super(config);
      this.alpha = config.alpha;
    }

    call(input) {
      return tf.tidy(() => {
        const x = input[0]; //tf.getExactlyOneTensor(input);
        return tf.sigmoid(x.mul(this.alpha)).mul(x);
      });
    }

    computeOutputShape(inputShape){
      return inputShape;
    }

    static get className() {
    return 'swish';
    }
}
export default Swish;
```

Loading:

```
import Swish from '/Users/alex/Documents/GitHub/TrueSkyApp/src/components/swish.js'


const modelJson = require('/Users/alex/Documents/GitHub/TrueSkyApp/assets/model/model.json');
const modelWeights = require('/Users/alex/Documents/GitHub/TrueSkyApp/assets/model/group1-shard1of1.bin');

class TFtest extends Component {
  private model: any
  state = {
    isModelReady: false
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await tf.ready()
    this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights));
    this.setState({
      isModelReady: true
    })

    //Output in Expo console
    console.log(this.state.isModelReady)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Model ready? {this.state.isModelReady ? <Text>Yes</Text> : ''}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code

Comment: @Yoskutik Added

Answer (score 3):

Even it the model has already been trained, the loaded model in js would need to look at the layers implementation to see given an input what might the output of the layer.

```
Error: Unknown activation: swish
```

Clearly the error suggests that the layer activation needs to be provided

**UPDATE**

The class needs to be registered

```
tf.serialization.registerClass(Swish)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on this? I've added in my original post the code I've tried, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: the class needs to be registered

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by doing the following:

Creating the swift class in the same file instead of importing it, and, adding

```
tf.serialization.registerClass(Swish)
```

after the class.